# how do django forms work

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django. Particularly I am reading about [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/) and I cannot understand how do they work.
Lets look at example code:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

why create class with unbounded members? there is no `self` statement.

I looked on Django source code itself:

```
class Form(BaseForm):
"A collection of Fields, plus their associated data."
# This is a separate class from BaseForm in order to abstract the way
# self.fields is specified. This class (Form) is the one that does the
# fancy metaclass stuff purely for the semantic sugar -- it allows one
# to define a form using declarative syntax.
# BaseForm itself has no way of designating self.fields.
__metaclass__ = DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass
```

Could you explain what is the role of `__metaclass__` ?

Comment: Here's something to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Comment: The `ContactForm` class has no unbound members; it only has attributes. That's perfectly legal in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form fields are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html), which are simply a class written to a [specific protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). The metaclass is the type of the class (since classes themselves, being objects, are instantiated from *something*).